# How to set VisualState INITIALIZATION via data binding in XAML, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am wondering what can I do with XAML, to initialize my UI element with the correct VisualState. **NOT WITH THE CODE BEHIND**. Because I know how to do it with C# code.

My UI element's XAML is somehow like this:

```
<Border x:Name="PART_Border" >

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CriticalnessStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="NonCritical"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Critical"/>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCritical}" Value="False">
            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="NonCritical"/>
        </ei:DataTrigger>

        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCritical}" Value="True">
            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Critical"/>
        </ei:DataTrigger>

    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</Border>
```

And it works perfectly when ***IsCritical*** property is set **after the UI element has been loaded**, but the problem is, I need the element, to load in the **correct** VisualState; I mean,

IsCritical = true => element loads in Critical state
IsCritical = false => element loads in NonCritical state

It is feasible by the C# code behind file, you can write a loaded event handler for your element, that sets the visual state by checking the corresponding DataContext property. I am wondering how to accomplish this with pure XAML.

By the way, **ei** and **i** point to these XML namespaces:

xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"                  xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"

Thanks.

Comment: IsCritical is a *source* property that is supposed to be implemented and set programmatically, either in a view model or in the control itself. You don't set the source property of a DataTrigger in XAML. Does it belong to your Control class or what is it?

Comment: @mm8 Yeah, it is a property of my ViewModel that is supposed to manage the state

Comment: Then you should set the default value of the property in the view model. See my answer. It makes no sense to try to set a default value for a source property in the view.

Comment: @mm8 I'm afraid I guess you got the whole point wrong, I want to change the IsCritical property programmatically, I don't want to set a default value! The problem is, that these binding expressions, DO NOT read the initial value of their target! I mean, if your viewmodel has IsCritical set to true, the binding for this condition will not fire! But when you change the property's value after the UI element has been constructed and shown, the binding fires.

Comment: @AmirMahdiNassiri *"The problem is, that these binding expressions, DO NOT read the initial value of their target!"* -- that's not a "problem". It's how WPF works, and it won't change just because you don't feel like learning how to use the framework. You have got the *whole point of bindings* wrong. You are doing this wrong. You do not understand WPF. You need to stop arguing and start listening. You will never win an argument with a compiler. Never.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I really want to listen :) why do you think I do not want to learn?! What do you suggest? What should I do in order that my View initializes in the correct visual state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented this **Behavior** class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Markup;

[ContentProperty("Conditions")]
public class VisualStateInitializer : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    private bool _useTransitions = true;
    public bool UseTransitions
    {
        get { return _useTransitions; }
        set { _useTransitions = value; }
    }

    public List<VisualStateCondition> Conditions { get; set; }

    public VisualStateInitializer()
    {
        Conditions = new List<VisualStateCondition>();
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.DataContext == null)
            return;

        foreach (var item in Conditions)
        {
            var dataContextType = AssociatedObject.DataContext.GetType();
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
            object value = null;

            var properties = item.PropertyName.Split('.');

            if (properties.Length > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(value != null)
                    {
                        dataContextType = value.GetType();
                        propertyInfo = dataContextType.GetProperty(properties[i]);
                        value = propertyInfo.GetValue(value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        propertyInfo = dataContextType.GetProperty(properties[i]);
                        value = propertyInfo.GetValue(AssociatedObject.DataContext);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                value = AssociatedObject.DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(item.PropertyName).GetValue(AssociatedObject.DataContext);
            }

            if (value != null && value.Equals(item.Value))
                VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(AssociatedObject, item.DesiredState, UseTransitions);
        }
    }
}
```

And the **VisualStateCondition** class is like this:

```
public class VisualStateCondition
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The PropertyName to look for in the associated object's <see cref="FrameworkElement.DataContext"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The Value to check for equality.
    /// </summary>
    public object Value { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="VisualState.Name"/> that is desired for the condition.
    /// </summary>
    public string DesiredState { get; set; }
}
```

And all I need to initialize my View class in the correct initial state is defining the **VisualStateConditions** like below:

**Note =>** " i " namespace in xaml refers to "System.Windows.Interactivity" of BlendSdk
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

```
<Border>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CriticalnessStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="NonCritical"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Critical"/>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <viewHelpers:VisualStateInitializer>

            <viewHelpers:VisualStateCondition PropertyName="IsCritical" DesiredState="Critical">
                <viewHelpers:VisualStateCondition.Value>
                    <system:Boolean>
                        True
                    </system:Boolean>
                </viewHelpers:VisualStateCondition.Value>
            </viewHelpers:VisualStateCondition>

            <viewHelpers:VisualStateCondition PropertyName="IsCritical" DesiredState="NonCritical">
                <viewHelpers:VisualStateCondition.Value>
                    <system:Boolean>
                        False
                    </system:Boolean>
                </viewHelpers:VisualStateCondition.Value>
            </viewHelpers:VisualStateCondition>

        </viewHelpers:VisualStateInitializer>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

</border>
```

where ViewHelpers is the namespace of my VisualStateInitializer & VisualStateCondition classes.
Can anyone suggest a better approach?

**UPDATE 1 =>** Editing property value retrieving, so that we can pass nested properties like:

```
<viewHelpers:VisualStateCondition PropertyName="X.Y.NestedProperty"
    Value="False"
    DesiredState="StateForNestedProperty"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`IsCritical` is a source property that is supposed to be implemented and set programmatically, either in a view model or in the control itself. So the default value should be set in the view model or wherever the property is implemented.

A `Style` or a `DataTrigger` can't set the value of a view model property.

Also, it's the implementation of the control that is supposed to define what visual state it's in. You do this by calling `VisualStateManager.GoToState` programmatically in the control class.

Comment: I'm afraid I guess you got the whole point wrong, I want to change the IsCritical property programmatically, I don't want to set a default value! The problem is, that these binding expressions, DO NOT read the initial value of their target! I mean, if your viewmodel has IsCritical set to true, the binding for this condition will not fire! But when you change the property's value after the UI element has been constructed and shown, the binding fires.

Comment: You are doing this wrong. The *implementation* of the control is supposed to define what visual state it's in. You do this by calling VisualStateManager.GoToState *programmatically*. Also, you don't need two DataTriggers that listens to the same bool source property.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I don't want to do it with C# source code, as this implementation is for a style that I don't want to have a code behind file. As I wrote, I know the solution via C# code. My visual state is set by the viewmodel object, and the viewmodel is responsible for the state of UI, I don't think that this approach is considered wrong! It is the whole MVVM idea. I will be glad if you can point me out how can I use one DataTrigger to handle both VisualState changes. You can only write action for when these triggers are fired by the CORRECT value, not the wrong value.

Comment: Why are you using visual states *and* data triggers? The view model is supposed to set source properties. It doesn't know anything about visual states. That's the responsibility of the control. Of course a border cannot change/set a source property. It's not an input control. It's a decorator.

Comment: "The ViewModel doesn't know anything about visual states" ? Are you sure about that? So what does this picture in [MSDN's page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) suppose to mean? So where do you maintain the business logic implemented for manipulating data via View?

Comment: The business logic belongs to the model.